# Using C++11 features in Oculus Mobile SDK samples

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, oculus

I want to use `std::shared_ptr` in the Oculus Mobile SDK Sample code. It won't compile. The error message is: `'shared_ptr' is not a member of 'std'`.

I'm using:

- Oculus Mobile SDK `0.6.0.1`
- Android NDK `r9d`
- Eclipse `4.2.1`

I confirmed that `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` is set to `4.8` in `Application.mk` (in the root directory `ovr_mobile_sdk_0.6.0.1`). I tried setting the cpp flags to C++11 values in every `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` I can find. I tried using Clang instead of GCC. I made sure the relevant include paths are added and tried adding others. I even tried the latest NDK `r10e`.

Unfortunately, none of this works. How can I use `std::shared_ptr` in the Oculus Mobile SDK sample code?